# Is there an alternative to "let!" to support function chaining?

Tags: f#

Is there an alternative to "let!" to support function chaining?

I currently have this:

```
async {

    let! result = token |> queryDay
    result |> toTransactions
}
```

However, I would like to consolidate the above code into something like this:

```
async {

    // NOTE: Async.Await isn't a thing
    let result = token |> queryDay |> Async.Await |> toTransactions
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you feel that consolidating the two-line code into a one-liner would be better? You can do this, as answered below, but I do not think there is much need for that in the first place.

Comment: I thought it would look cleaner and be more idiomatic to FP.

Comment: In some FP languages, avoidining readable code is idiomatic :-) but as far as F# goes, I think using `let!` is perfectly fine. The fact that you name the variable makes your code more self-documenting too. I'd even avoid the pipes and just write `let! dayData = queryDay token` and `return toTransactiosn result`. There's no need to force code into using constructs that are helpful in other contexts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your examples I'm assuming that:

```
queryDay : 'a -> Async<'b>
toTransactions : 'b -> Async<'c>
```

Chaining monadic functions like that is called ["bind"](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-bind//). This is the core operation of a monad, the very essense of it. In fact the `let!` construct gets desugared into a call to `async.Bind`, and so does `do!`.

Unfortunately, the F# standard library doesn't offer a built-in standalone implementation of `bind` for `Async`. But there is one [in `FSharpx`](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Async/reference/fsharpx-control-asyncextensions.html) that you can use:

```
open FSharpx.Control

async {
   let! result = token |> queryDay |> Async.bind toTransactions
}
```

Or if you don't want to use `FSharpx`, you can easily make one yourself by delegating to the computation builder:

```
module Async =
    let bind f a = async.Bind(a, f)
```